Debian Ifupdown /etc/network/interfaces : network vs netmask
I came accross the following bit of network conf and the part I don't get is the keyword network.
Given that netmask is fed, what is the purpose of network ?
Disclaimer : I'm not a guru of network configuration, so sorry i the question seems dumb.
On Debian Jessie(8)
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address xx.201.4.132
        netmask 255.255.255.192
        network xx.201.4.128
        gateway xx.201.4.129

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address xx.201.69.4
        netmask 255.255.255.192
        network xx.201.69.0


I searched thoroughly in the manpage, this keyword is never mentionned.
I've seen a mention of it in the Debian Wiki page on Network Comfiguration but that's all:

Configuring the interface manually
If you're configuring it manually then something like this will set the default gateway (network, broadcast and gateway are optional):


It has no purpose whatsoever. The keyword doesn't exist in the Debian ifupdown source code among the other recognized keywords in inet.defn (and did not exist in Jessie's 0.7.53).
The keyword did exist in ifupdown version 0.6, where it was marked as "required for 2.0.x kernels" (which were 1996–1999, with the last LTS until 2004), and would have been directly translated to a route add -net %network% call, presumably to add a "local subnet" route that was for some reason not yet automatic.
This code was limited to mylinuxver() < mylinux(2,1,100) so it most likely became thoroughly obsolete at around 2000 when the 2.2.x series of Linux became commonplace (Jessie provides 3.16), and it was removed from ifupdown around 2007. Modern kernels automatically add the xx.201.4.128/26 route as soon as you assign an IP address with /26 netmask.
Nowadays it just sticks around in tutorials that are a 15th-generation copypaste of older tutorials.1

Given that netmask is fed

At the time, ifupdown apparently did not yet support custom derivation of missing parameters – it only seems to have had direct %variable% substitution, so if a command needed to be run with the "network address", it had to be supplied manually from the config file.
Later versions of ifupdown do support custom 'conversion' functions to derive parameters (e.g. broadcast from address+netmask)... but at that point, the kernel is already capable of the same all by itself, so it's moot.


1 …just like the 'broadcast' keyword that is still commonly repeated. (There's probably still one or two networks in the world that still use all-zeros broadcast as a relic from 1980s, but the rest of the world has firmly settled on all-ones and the software knows that, so there is no longer any need to specify the broadcast address manually.)

Thanks so much for the thorough answer. The saddest thing is that I've found this entry again on hosts with Debian 9, 10. Because of the absence of warning in the networking.service logs, this pattern might still keep going :)
